# django does not display form errors

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display errors when a user try to login/register with wrong information

I have this codes but errors does not show in browser

I've wrote this code by looking to another project that I done when I was learning Django but now it's not working!

hers is codes of my project

views.py :

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')

    form = loginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')

    content = {
        "form": loginForm,
        "title": "Login",
    }
    return render(request, 'login.html', content)

#---------------------------------------------

def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    form = registerForm(request.POST or None)

    content = {
        "form": registerForm,
        "title": "Register",
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'register.html', content)
```

forms.py :

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))


class registerForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }), label='Password Confirm')

    def clean_username(self):
        user_name = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        user_exists = User.objects.filter(username=user_name).exists()
        if user_exists:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username is in user")
        return user_name

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email is in use!!')
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        pass1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        pass2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if pass1 != pass2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords does not match')
        return pass2
```

html(it's for register but login is the same) :

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <h3 class="text-center">{{ title }}</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                        <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                        <p class="bg-danger text-light">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                        <p class="bg-danger text-light">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
                        <p class="bg-danger text-light">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">{{ form.username.label }}</label>
                    {{ form.username }}
                    <br>

                    <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_email }}">{{ form.email.label }}</label>
                    {{ form.email }}
                    <br>

                    <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">{{ form.password.label }}</label>
                    {{ form.password }}
                    <br>

                    <label for="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}">{{ form.password2.label }}</label>
                    {{ form.password2 }}

                    <hr>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Instead `"form": loginForm` use `"form": form` and the same in your registerPage: `"form": registerForm` > `"form": form`

Comment: what a mistake I made . thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add to your context unbound Class `loginForm` - [See The Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#module-django.forms)

Use bound form `form = registerForm(request.POST)` and `form.is_valid()`.

So in your views change it your :

`"form": loginForm` to `"form": form`

`"form": registerForm` to `"form": form`